How do I modify the built in web server on my M2 Mac running Sequoia
I have an M2 Mac Mini 2023. I'm running Sequoia 15.1. It has a running web server, obviously Apache, but I can't modify it because it's on a system drive.
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
How can I modify it, or indeed even stop the server running?
It's refusing all commands.

These are, as the path implies, template files. The actual configuration can be found and edited at /etc/apache2.
To start/stop the web server (it doesn't run by default), use
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

To reread config files if it is already running, sudo apachectl graceful can be used.
